# Rails version automatically downgraded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu on my PC and installed the latest version of rails. It worked successfully and I was able to create an app. The version installed was 3.0.5 I believe.  Today rails -v returns 2.3.5. Anyone know why it would make that change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would change if you ran `gem install rails -v 2.3.5` or something similar. You can fix it by running `gem install rails -v 3.0.5`.